# Determine if all n x n matrices $A$ such that $A^T=-A$ is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Consider a 3 x 3 square matrix A. The entries $a^T_{11} = a_{11}, a^T_{22} = a_{22}, a^T_{33} = a_{33}$.
Therefore if $A^T = -A$, then $a_{11} = -a_{11}, a_{22} = -a_{22}, a_{33} = -a_{33}$ and the diagonal of $A^T$, $A$ and $-A$ consists of all zeros.

If $A^T = -A$, then the entries
$
a^T_{21}=a_{12}=-a_{21} \\
a^T_{31}=a_{13}=-a_{31} \\
a^T_{32}=a_{23}=-a_{32}
$

Therefore, $A$ is of the form:

$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
-a_{12} & 0 & a_{23} \\
-a_{13} & -a_{23} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

which is of the form:

$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & k & k \\
-k & 0 & k \\
-k & -k & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

All n x n matrices such that $A^T = -A$ will have this pattern. To show that these matrices form a subspace, we show that:
1) Two such matrices A and B of the same dimension are closed under addition
2) Such matrices are closed under scalar multiplication

for addition:

$A + B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_{12} + b_{12} & a_{13} + b_{13} \\
-a_{12} - b_{12} & 0 & a_{23} + b_{23} \\
-a_{13} - b_{13} & -a_{23}- b_{23} & 0\end{bmatrix}
$

or

$A + B = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & a_{12} - b_{12} & a_{13} - b_{13} \\
-a_{12} + b_{12} & 0  & a_{23} - b_{23} \\
-a_{13} + b_{13} & -a_{23} + b_{23} & 0\end{bmatrix}
$

which are of the form:

$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & k & k \\
-k & 0 & k \\
-k & -k & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$
Therefore closed under addition.
For scalar multiplication:
$ cA = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & ca_{12} & ca_{13} \\
-ca_{12} & 0 & ca_{23} \\
-ca_{13} & -ca_{23} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Which is of the form:
$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & k & k \\
-k & 0 & k \\
-k & -k & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Therefore the n x n matrices such that $A^T = -A$ are subspaces.
Firstly does anyone agree with this. Also, if it is correct or almost correct, are there any suggestions to make this much more succinct?
Thanks.

Comment: You can  save ink by not computing the components. The matrix zero satisfies $0^T=-0$. If $A^T=-A$, $B^T=-B$ and $a,b$ are scalars, then $(aA+bB)^T=aA^T+bB^t=-aA-bB=-(aA+bB)$. This shows that the set of solutions is a non-empty subset of all the matrices that is closed by linear combinations.

Comment: Stylistically, you also have a couple of problems. First off, showing the $3\times 3$ case is not sufficient for the general case, even though it suggests the general pattern. You should also be careful with statements like
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & k & k \\
-k & 0 & k \\
-k & -k & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$
It makes it look as if you intend each of those $k$ have the same value, which isn't true at all. Something like 
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & k & l \\
-k & 0 & m \\
-l & -m & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
is better.

Comment: Oh, yes I agree with the k,l,m.

Comment: Oh, very nice @USir470888, thanks.